# Passing params[:thing] to another function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, i got the following code to parse a CSV file:

```
CSV.foreach(params[:file]) do |row|
    #bingbangbong
end
```

But I have two functions, one for show the CSV parsed file, and another one to save it on a db.

My question is: How can I pass the `params[:file]` var to another function, something like this:

```
def show_CSV
    CSV.foreach(params[:file]) do |row|
        #Showing the parsed CSV
    end
end

def save_CSV
    CSV.foreach(params[:file]) do |row|
        #Showing the parsed CSV
    end
end
```

But, without making the user to upload the file again.

Comment: Any controller method has access to the `params` function, which returns the request parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def show_and_save_CSV(options={})
  CSV.foreach(params[:file]) do |row|
    if options[:show]
      #Showing the parsed CSV
    end
    if options[:save]
      # save
    end
  end
end
```

Just remember that `CSV.foreach` loops through the lines of the provided file, so this way you will read the file just once.

```
def save_CSV
  show_and_save_CSV(:save => true)
end

def show_CSV
  show_and_save_CSV(:show => true)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code that currently contains your `CSV.foreach(params[:file])`, just call two different functions instead - one to save the file, and one to show it:

```
def show_CSV f
    CSV.foreach f do |row|
        # show
    end
end

def save_CSV! f
    CSV.foreach f do |row|
        # save
    end
end

def some_calling_function # I'm guessing... in your controller?
    ...
    save_CSV! params[:file]
    show_CSV params[:file]
    ...
end
```